# Responsive divs maintain equal width x height proportions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, grid

I am developing a CMS and my client requires a responsive grid of posts in the thumbnail format. My problem is that I cannot control all the images they will use and am looking for a way to set a height in proportion to the original width of the image used.

This will make more sense with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjwoma2/U2ZkU/

As you can see, the images are of different heights and it throws off the grid. What I want is  to set a specific height to width proportion of the class `.two` and just set `overflow: hidden` if the image height is beyond that of the predetermined proportional height of the `.two` div.

Is there a script which can even do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. If your proportion is predefined, you could do something like this:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var proportion = 1.75;    // width / height

    $('.two').each(function(){
       $(this).css('height', (parseInt($(this).width())/proportion)+'px'); 
    });    

});
```

And in your **CSS**:

```
.two {float: left; width: 50%; overflow: hidden;}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2ZkU/3/

---

Or a more advanced approach (imgs dimensions are also modified): http://jsfiddle.net/U2ZkU/5/

Comment: Thanks Marcelo that seems like a great option. For some reason when I implement that code, the grid (i.e., `.two` div) are all stacked on top of one another and like a deck or cards. Their height is also squished. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Mhh... if it worked in JsFiddle but not in your site... another CSS o script may be involved. Try adding some `console.log()` in the JS (for example `console.log(parseInt($(this).width()))` at the beginning of the `each`, to see if width is correctly fetched)

Comment: Like this?

`$('.two').console.log(parseInt($(this).width())).each(function(){`

Comment: No, in another line, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U2ZkU/6/. Then check your browser's console.

Comment: Ok, here is what I got:

http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/9021/screenshot20130605at210.png

(My `.two` is actually set to 25%, FYI)

Comment: Your `img` height is not being fetched (is there a image there?). Anyway, it shouldn't affect the div behaviour, as it's width and height are correctly fetched and calculated. I'm almost sure that another CSS is affecting `.two` class. If don't, I have no more clues :-/

Comment: Hmm.. No CSS... It is giving the div a height of 14px, thats too small, it should be more like 283px

Comment: @N-WS Mhh seems that it's fetching the *%* as *px*, and not the **real** dimensions. Are you using the latest jQuery version? What about your browser?

Comment: jQuery 1.10.0 and Google Chrome

Comment: @N-WS Sorry, no more ideas. Check your elements console to double-check that there is no another CSS rule applying there.